# Error with Jquery, json in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome

Recently I purchased a chat script which works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome. I have located the error, but cannot solve it. The code is ...

```
function checknew(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "user_chat/chat.php?action=checknew",
        type : "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
            error: alert('error');
        success: function(data) {
```

When I check it in firefox, everything is working fine. But in Chrome the alert message triggers. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Look in the `net` tab of debug tools (press F12) and see what the server is sending. Also, consider using a proper error handler `error: function(xhr, Status, Error){ /*Put a breakpoint in this function or alert Status and Error to see what's wrong*/};`

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I mean how can I see thats what wrong?

Comment: Thanks, The error is "syntax error: unexpected token" and the status is "parseerror". But what would I do now?

Comment: It's probably the semi-colon after your alert function. You're supposed to be in a list of properties - everything else ends with a comma. Oh beg pardon - if that's what the alerts are showing, it's probably a problem in your chat.php script

Comment: What happens if you browse to `user_chat/chat.php?action=checknew`? I think it's a problem with your PHP script

Answer (score 0):

The `error` attribute expects a function *reference*, but this is a *call*.

So, replace:

```
error: alert('error');
```

with:

```
error: function () {
    alert('error');
},
```

This assigns an anonymous function to `error`, that calls `alert('error')`, instead of trying to call it when a definition was expected.

Comment: How will this help since Chrome is already showing the error alert? (Although I agree it's bad practice to do it as the OP has done)

Comment: The alert message is being showed because `alert` was called. I have no idea why it's not showing in other browsers, because it should.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But why in firefox there is no error, but in Chrome it's not working?

Comment: You will have to be a bit more detailed in your original question for me to be able to answer that. Maybe make a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
    async: false,
        error: alert('error');
    success: function(data) {
```

to this:

```
async: false,
error: function(xhr, Status, Error){
           alert('Status: ' + Status); //Add a breakpoint (see below)
           alert('Error: ' + Error);
       },
success: function(data) {
```

Also, you should get out of the habit of using `alert()` and learn to use a debugger. Chrome comes with one built in, Firefox does too but IMHO the Firebug addon is better.

In Chrome, press <kbd>F12</kbd>. Go to the `Sources` tab, use the menu @ the left to find your page and double-click on the line indicated above. This will add a breakpoint.

Now, when the javascript runs, when it gets to that line, it will stop and let you look at variables, error messages, etc...

Also, the `Network` tab shows every web request made by that page (download images, get css, AJAX calls, etc). You can see if they succeeded or not, what error was returned by the server, etc...

There is a really in-depth guide on using the Chrome tools [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). Firebug for FF is almost identical to use (although IMHO a slightly more intuitive interface).

Finally, all the dev tools mentioned have a "Console" where certain information (like recent warnings and errors) are shown. You can even output your own messages there (google `Javascript Console.Log`.

Comment: I console tab, the only error messages I can see is the server response of a few images on the page is returning 404 error. Simply "Image not found".

Comment: Look at the "XHR" filter (Net tab). That's the one that relates to XMLHttpRequests (aka AJAX) calls. You should see one entry for every AJAX calls. If the status is 200 (or 2xx) then your success function should be called with data. Anything else will call your error function with a problem. You haven't said what happens when you browse to the Url in question using your browser instead of making an AJAX call?